# nginx with NJS compile error

Tags: nginx, compiler-errors

**What's wrong compiling nginx with njs? Example:**

Download:

```
# cd /usr/src/
# git clone https://github.com/nginx/njs.git
# wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
# tar -zxf nginx-1.10.1.tar.gz
```

Configure OK:

```
# cd nginx-1.10.1
# ./configure --add-dynamic-module=../njs/nginx
...
adding module in ../njs/nginx
 + ngx_js_module was configured
...
Configuration summary
  + using system PCRE library
  + OpenSSL library is not used
  + md5: using system crypto library
  + sha1: using system crypto library
  + using system zlib library

  nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
  nginx modules path: "/usr/local/nginx/modules"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/usr/local/nginx/conf"
  nginx configuration file: "/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"
  nginx http uwsgi temporary files: "uwsgi_temp"
  nginx http scgi temporary files: "scgi_temp"
```

And make error:

```
# make
...
cc -c -fPIC -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I ../njs/nginx/../nxt -I ../njs/nginx/../njs -I ../njs/nginx/../nxt -I ../njs/nginx/../njs -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules \
    -o objs/addon/nginx/ngx_stream_js_module.o \
    ../njs/nginx/ngx_stream_js_module.c
../njs/nginx/ngx_stream_js_module.c:10:24: fatal error: ngx_stream.h: no such file or directory
 #include <ngx_stream.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: ** [objs/addon/nginx/ngx_stream_js_module.o] Erro 1
make[1]: Saindo do diretório `/usr/src/nginx-1.10.1'
make: ** [build] Erro 2
```

Site: github.com/nginx/njs
Readme: github.com/nginx/njs/blob/master/README
Order: www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/nginScript/

Comment: Well, apparently the `ngx_stream.h` doesn't exist or is in the wrong location. Have you tried symlinking it to proper location and recompiling?

Comment: Yes , I did as the documentation procedure. I did the compilation in other way, see:
`cd /usr/src/njs/nginx
# gcc -c -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/core -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/stream -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/objs -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/os/unix -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/http -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/event -I /usr/src/nginx-1.10.1/src/http/modules -I /usr/src/njs/nxt -I /usr/src/njs/njs -Icore -Ianimator -Iimages -Ianother_dir -Iyet_another_dir ngx_http_js_module.c`
Result: `ngx_http_js_module.o`.

Comment: But when I compile the `ngx_stream_js_module.c`. It Shows another error, see sample: `ngx_stream_js_module.c:53:5: error: unknown type name ‘ngx_stream_variable_value_t’`

Comment: In case any one is still looking for answers, please use nginx:nginx:1.19 onwards since the njs was made native module. It should just like that work as is. Do let me know if you want a working example, I will upload to github.